# Call method every time any method is called without using __call

Tags: php

How can I execute a given method or given script every time any method in a given object is called?  My purpose is for temporary testing, and I would rather not have to edit each method to add `$this->testLogger();`, and then remove it when done.  Note that `__call` is not an option as methods `m1`, `m2`, etc do exist.

```
class Foo
{
    private $bla;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->bla=123;
    }
    public function m1(){}
    public function m2(){}
    public function m3(){}
    public function m4(){}
    public function testLogger()
    {
        echo("bla value is $this->bla\n");
    }
}
$foo=new Foo;
$foo->m1(); //bla value is 123
$foo->m2(); //bla value is 123
$foo->m3(); //bla value is 123
$foo->m4(); //bla value is 123
```

Comment: You're probably looking for a decorator/facade; a wrapper objects that uses `__call` to invoke methods of the wrapped object, where you can add any additional logging you want.

Comment: @deceze  But isn't `__call` only invoked if the called method doesn't exist?   Per http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call: `__call() is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in an object context.`

Comment: Read again: *a different object which __wraps__ your object under test.* E.g. `new LoggingFacade(new Foo)`…

Comment: Your wrapper will not have any methods except `__call`.  Inside `__call` (or via __construct) you create `Foo` as a property of wrapper and call it's methods with logging.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thank you

Comment: You seem to be trying to do some sort of debugging. If that's the use case then I suggest using xdebug instead

Comment: You can give a look at ticks, that allows you to define a function that you register with register_tick_function() and that will be executed between each line of your code. Ticks pretty much allows you to create your own debugger